# I need help finding my USB connected devices

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, vmware, usb-drive

How do i get the USB device connected to my computer to show my connected devices if i am running a virtual version of Ubuntu 14.04. I am using VMware and I have no clue how to get it to work.What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Read here: [Connecting USB Devices to Virtual Machines](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-E003456F-EB94-4B53-9082-293D9617CB5A.html)

> On Linux hosts, Workstation uses the USB device file system to connect to USB devices. If the USB device file system is not located in /proc/bus/usb, you must mount the USB file system to that location.

As root, mount the **USB file system**

```
mount -t usbfs none /proc/bus/usb
```

Connect the USB device to the host system.

To connect **USB HIDs** to a Virtual Machine:

> - Select the virtual machine and select VM > Settings.
> - On the Hardware tab, select USB Controller.
> - Select Show all USB input devices.
> - This option allows users to use special USB HIDs inside the virtual machine.
> - Click OK to save your changes.
> - Power on the virtual machine.
> - HIDs appear in the Removable Devices menu.

Source: [Connect USB HIDs to a Virtual Machine](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-07883F0A-E7B5-4CBA-837D-0BA986E8B900.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should first deal with vmware workstation :

```
1- Plug in the usb
2- Power on virtual machine
3- in vmware , click on the virtual machine , and in the up there is option named VM
4- click removable device
5- You will see your usb , click connect
```

Now you can see your Usb on Desktop , or in `/media`