# Integrated camera vmware/Ubuntu not detected

Tags: usb, vmware, camera

I have a Lenovo 700 15isk laptop. while working on project on vmware (virtual machine) in ubuntu 16.04.

I came to the part where I need to use my integrated laptop camera (which works on windows 10), but the camera is not detected. I installed cheese and it says "no device found".

The output of `lsusb` command is:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

When I click on the bar camera icon and choose connect(disconnect from host) it gives me the output on screen:

> The connection for the USB device "ACER Lenovo EasyCamera" was unsuccessful.
>   Driver error

Additional drivers menu:

[image]

Changing it doesn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need help finding my USB connected devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455465/i-need-help-finding-my-usb-connected-devices)

Comment: Nope. all my connected usb devices work (usb, android, etc..) but not integrated camera..  Selecting "Show all USB input devices" didn't help..

Comment: I don't see any (non-virtual) USB devices in the listing in your question. Could you please explain the *exact* steps that you took to pass the USB device through from the host system to the guest system?

Comment: No steps my friend. I put the usb in usb port and everything works. My usb, my android.. they are listed with lsusb command

Comment: Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13fe:4200 Kingston Technology Company Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: If you didn't perform any steps then you obviously didn't follow the instructions in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: Ok don't be mad bro, this is one of the first times I use anything associated with linux (it really confused me that I can't use enter for new line). I meant you asked me before posting question what I performed before connecting usb..

Comment: Anyways i solved the problem! This is super weird but when i connect android to ubuntu and than click on the bar: connect(disconnect from host), camera starts working. I checked it few times cause i was shocked, and it worked every time. That's it hope it will help people with same problem. David thank you vm for your effort and also for educating me about how to write a comments! ;)

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Comment: You might have to remove line `usb.restrictions.defaultAllow = "FALSE"` from `*.vmx` file as described [here](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/All-USB-devices-are-greyed-out/td-p/2878067). Then select desired Controller version from `Virtual Machine Settings > USB Controller`. Finally from removable devices menu, select your cam connected to host or integrated cam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was to connect any usb device to ubuntu and than when ubuntu recognizes it, connect the camera. Also you have to go to virtual machine settings and change USB compatibility to 1.1

I guess this is because lenovo integrated camera is connected on usb 1.1 port.

Answer (score 0):

"Also you have to go to virtual machine settings and change USB compatibility to 1.1"

I had to change compatibility to 3.1 --- then it worked!